# Calculations in Dirac's bra-ket notation

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Let $|f\rangle$ be a norm-1 vector in a Hilbert space $H$.
Let $|f_1\rangle,...,|f_n\rangle$ be other norm-1 vectors and let $e_1,...,e_n>0$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i=1$, such that
$$|f\rangle\langle f|=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i|f_i\rangle\langle f_i|.$$

> How do I prove that $|f\rangle\langle f|=|f_i\rangle\langle f_i|$ for every $i$?

I truly have no idea where to begin this. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The idea is to note that if any of the $f_ii$ on the right are linearly independent, then we no longer have a rank-1 operator on the right.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm not sure what to make of that

Comment: Any part in particular that you don't understand?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why would that mean that $|f\rangle\langle f|=|f_i\rangle\langle f_i|$?

Comment: Both operators need to have $f$ in their range (so at least one $f_i$ is $f$. The $f_i$ can't be linearly independent, so every $f_i$ is $f$ multiplied by a phase factor, which is to say that $f_i \rangle \langle f_i = f \rangle \langle f$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom And why must we have a rank-1 operator?

Comment: Because the two operators are equal, and $f \rangle \langle f$ has rank $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What do you mean by phase factor exactly in this case?

Comment: A phase factor is a complex number is magnitude $1$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Last question (thanks for having patience): Why does the $f_i$ not being lin independent imply that $f_i$ is $f$ multiplied by a phase factor?

Comment: Remember the definition of linear independence, and that $f_i$ is (according to the question) a unit vector